# Derivative of $\cos x$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

We all know that the integration of $\cos(x) \ dx$ is $\sin(x) + c$,
Since $\cos(x) \ dx$ is area, the dimension is unit squared.
So is $\sin(x) + c$ also having dimension in unit squares?
I mean at $\sin(\frac{π}{2})$ the value is $1$, so is it presented as $1$ unit squared?

Am I missing some point? Please help me out on this.

Comment: Please use mathjax. Regarding your question: The assumption that an an integral gives an area of dimension unit squared is simply wrong.

Comment: Sorry I'll learn mathjax as soon as possible. However, isn't it weird how an area doesn't have a dimension of L squared?

Comment: No it isnt, it is not necessarily a spatial area. E.g. if you integrate a velocity over time, you get a length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of a trigonometric function is dimensionless. While $x$ would have the dimension of $k^{-1}$ in $\cos kx$, the problem at hand has $k=1$ so $x$ is dimensionless. We therefore can't uniquely specify a dimension for a trigonometric function, whether we obtained it by differentiation, integration, neither, or one repeated. Note the value of $\cos kx$ is dimensionless too, regardless of $k$.

Comment: I understand , but isn't it weird how an area doesn't have a dimension L^2?

Comment: @NightcoRohak However, an area under $L_1\cos\frac{x}{L_2}$ with $L_1,\,L_2$ each of dimension $L$ **will** have dimension $L^2$.

Comment: Well that true. So you are saying that the result of an integration is dimensionless if our graph is dimensionless. So the integration of cosxdx is just a number, which happens to equal the length of the graph of sinx + c right? Or am I again missing something. Sorry for the silly questions , but I think you can understand that I'm very new to calculus.

Comment: @NightcoRohak Since the output of $\cos x$ is a dimensionless number, it must be followed by some kind of unit to be able to represent a dimensional physical quantity. In other words, $\cos xdx$ is the magnitude of the area, but the actual area of the element is $\cos xdx$ squared units. Upon integration, the unit/suffixed 'squared units' persists, so the area is actually $(\sin x+c)$ squared units, which further implies that $\sin x$, like its argument $x$, is dimensionless and just gives the magnitude.

Comment: @NightcoRohak We were all new to it once. The important thing to understand is that while integration *can* obtain an area, it's not limited to that. The dimension of an integral (be it definite it but indefinite), with respect to $x$, of $f(x)$ is the dimension of $xf(x)$. It can be anything, especially in physical applications.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri  Oh I see, so we just integrate a function divided into dx parts and find out the answer , which is a number just like that. But we always attribute a unit to it later in application.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for explaining it wonderfully. So the integration of any function divided into small pieces on the normal dimensionless x-y plane , has to be dimensionless right? But since we can use that area for practical purposes, we often attribute a unit to it, isn't it?

Comment: @NightcoRohak Yes, that's right. The unit is application specific, while the integration is not.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri  Thank you so much sir, I'm genuinely happy that I have cleared my doubt at last!